# How to Sort a slice of empty Interface that have a field in common?

Tags: go, struct, interface, slice

I have multiple struct :

```
type FooStruct struct {
  ID int
  Field1 int
  CommonID int
}

type BarStruct struct {
  ID int
  Field2 int
  CommonID int
}

type FighterStruct struct {
  ID int
  Field3 int
  CommonID int
}
```

1- They are all held into different slices : sliceOfFooStruct , sliceOfBarStruct , sliceofFighterStruct

2- i'm iterating over each slice and inserting them , unsorted, into a commun `var commonSlice []interface{}` slice

3- Then i need to sort them by CommonID into that slice and that's where i kind of get stuck.

i'm trying to do :

```
sort.Slice(commonSlice, func(i, j int) bool { return commonSlice[i].CommonID > commonSlice[j].CommonID })
```

but i'm getting the error

`commonSlice[i].CommonID undefined (type interface {} is interface with no methods)`

I've tried to cast a type aswell doing commonSlice[i].CommonID.(int) but it doesn't work either.

Tried something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32277884/golang-type-interface-is-interface-with-no-methods) too with an anonymous struct and the CommonID field but it didn't work.

I would assume it could work if i directly cast the type of the actual struct being compared but hardcoding the type would defeat the whole purpose of the "commonSlice" .

How is that done ? Should i do things differently ?

Comment: "Should i do things differently ?" Yes, do not use the empty interface.

Comment: Yes it's already been answered by icza and i'm not using a custom interface anymore.thanks anyway for the great contribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the element type of your `commonSlice` is `interface{}` you can't access any fields of the values as that allows storing any values, even values that are not structs.

One discouraged way would be to use reflection to access the `CommonID` field, but that's ugly and slow. For reference, here's how it would look like:

```
all := []interface{}{
    FooStruct{11, 22, 31},
    BarStruct{21, 32, 33},
    FighterStruct{21, 32, 32},
}

sort.Slice(all, func(i, j int) bool {
    commonID1 := reflect.ValueOf(all[i]).FieldByName("CommonID").Int()
    commonID2 := reflect.ValueOf(all[j]).FieldByName("CommonID").Int()
    return commonID1 > commonID2
})

fmt.Println(all)
```

This outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/GpMTHdlpx9I)):

```
[{21 32 33} {21 32 32} {11 22 31}]
```

But instead create an interface that describes a way to access the `CommonID` field:

```
type HasCommonID interface {
    GetCommonID() int
}
```

And make your struts implement this interface:

```
func (f FooStruct) GetCommonID() int     { return f.CommonID }
func (b BarStruct) GetCommonID() int     { return b.CommonID }
func (f FighterStruct) GetCommonID() int { return f.CommonID }
```

And store your values in a slice of this interface:

```
all := []HasCommonID{
    FooStruct{11, 22, 31},
    BarStruct{21, 32, 33},
    FighterStruct{21, 32, 32},
}
```

And then you can use `GetCommonID()` method to access this in the `less()` function:

```
sort.Slice(all, func(i, j int) bool {
    return all[i].GetCommonID() > all[j].GetCommonID()
})
```

This will output the same, try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/jlwSYE8ukt8).

This is much cleaner, faster, extendable.

To avoid repetition, you could "outsource" common fields and methods to a struct and embed that in all your struts:

```
type Common struct {
    CommonID int
}

func (c Common) GetCommonID() int { return c.CommonID }

type FooStruct struct {
    ID     int
    Field1 int
    Common
}

type BarStruct struct {
    ID     int
    Field2 int
    Common
}

type FighterStruct struct {
    ID     int
    Field3 int
    Common
}
```

Note: `GetCommonID()` is only defined once, for `Common`, other types do not need to add it. And then using it:

```
all := []HasCommonID{
    FooStruct{11, 22, Common{31}},
    BarStruct{21, 32, Common{33}},
    FighterStruct{21, 32, Common{32}},
}

sort.Slice(all, func(i, j int) bool {
    return all[i].GetCommonID() > all[j].GetCommonID()
})
```

Output is the same, try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/XNRCiiQphJV).

This also allows you to extend the common field and method list in a singe place (`Common`) without further repetition.

Comment: oh nice. Thanks alot.